# what is function of default tables in ORCL database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, sysdba

I installed oracle 10g software and connected to ORCL database in SQL Developer. when I expand the tables section I see a lot of tables there like in image below. What are these tables for? HOw can I create a database that does not have these tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connected as SYS user. Now you should create your user with command

`CREATE USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY password`

After it you will be able to connect as new user which doesn't have any tables.
Maybe you will need to `GRANT CREATE SESSION to user_name` to be able to connect.

In Oracle each user has its own schema where stored all user's objects (tables, functions, packages and so on)

Comment: @Taiana  now if i try to login with this new username/password i get error message insufficient privileges. How do I give access to this 'ORCL' database to this new user?

Comment: @WasimQadir Did you grant `create session` privilege to at least let the new user create a session. Anyway, you current topic is marked as duplicate, so it is answered. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: @Taiana I did. still getting the same error